# Module version mismatch when using modified version of text-buffer package for Atom

Tags: node.js, atom-editor

I'm trying to make some modifications to the text-buffer package for Atom. I checked out text-buffer, made the modifications, and according to [flight manual](http://flight-manual.atom.io/behind-atom/sections/developing-node-modules/) I do:

```
$ npm install
$ npm link
$ apm rebuild
```

After solving many problems with install and rebuild this finally works. Now I go to the folder with Atom checked out and do:

```
$ npm link text-buffer
$ script\build
```

This completes successfully. Now I go to the directory with the built version of Atom, and running Atom fails with the following visible in console:

```
Module version mismatch. Expected 47, got 46.
Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 47, got 46.
    at Error (native)
    at process.module.(anonymous function) [as dlopen] (ATOM_SHELL_ASAR.js:159:20)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:450:18)
    at Object.module.(anonymous function) [as .node] (ATOM_SHELL_ASAR.js:170:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\temp\atom-dev\resources\app.asar\node_modules\nslog\lib\nslog.js:5:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\temp\atom-dev\resources\app.asar\node_modules\nslog\lib\nslog.js:15:4)
```

Searching online suggested to do

```
npm rebuild
```

I did this inside my text-buffer repository, then repeated the steps above with the same error in Atom. I also called npm update from both repositories. Calling npm rebuild from my Atom repository causes this failure.

```
  keyboard-layout-observer-windows.cc
..\src\keyboard-layout-observer-windows.cc(92): error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated [C:\
Users\Tomek\Documents\GitHub\atom\node_modules\atom-keymap\node_modules\keyboard-layout\build\keyboard-layout-observer.
vcxproj]
```

I did build Atom before linking the changed package and that worked fine. What is actually causing the mismatch and how do I fix it? Do I need to call npm rebuild from the Atom directory to fix this?